# Show a ribbon tab programmatically floating over the form

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2016, ribbonx

When the ribbon is minimized, showing tabs names only.
[image]

I Can show the ribbon for a certain tab, floating over the form, by pressing on the tab name with the mouse. 
 
[image]

How can I mimic this behavior using VBA?    
 
**Edit**  ------ 16/08/2018 -------------
I did found a solution using `SendKeys "%" & "L"` i.e. 
But sometimes it goes out of synch and the letters gets writen in the focused textbox :(

Answer (score 0):

Access VBA does not provide the ability to manipulate built-in ribbons. You can activate only the tab of a custom ribbon:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/office-shared-vba/articles/iribbonui-activatetab-method-office?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have the tab Control ID from the XML, but how do I get the reference to IRibbonUI from my actual ribbon  ?

Comment: your answer is not what I was after since it only works when ribbon is wide open, not when it is collapsed